# Sequential Searching

Tags: java, search, sequential

Ok I am relatively new to Java Programming, but have previous experience in C++. I want to search an array for a specific item, but what if there are more than one of the same specific item? Would it be best to use a temporary array to store all found items in the array and return the temporary array?

Note: I'm trying to find the best way of doing this with memory management and speed. And it's not for Home work:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a "ready to use" implementation like a HashMap. You say "search", so I believe that you have a searchkey (in my proposal the String) under wich you can store your data (for example an Integer).

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>  map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>(); 

    void storeValue(final String key, final Integer value) {
        List<Integer> l = this.map.get(key);
        if (l == null) {
            synchronized (this.map) {
                if (l == null) {
                    l = new Vector<Integer>();
                    this.map.put(key, l);
                }
            }
        }
        l.add(value);
    }

    List<Integer> searchByKey(final String key) {
        return this.map.get(key);
    }
```

With this, you can store multiple Integers @ one key. Of course you can store other Object than the Integers.

Answer (score 4):

If you able to skip Java, then in Scala it will be much easier:

```
scala> val a = Array(4, 6, 8, 9, 4, 2, 4, 2)
a: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6, 8, 9, 4, 2, 4, 2)

scala> a.filter(_ == 4)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(4, 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use apache commons lib, which solve a lot of issues. Use this if you want to filter by predicate and select sub array

```
        CollectionUtils.filter(
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5}),
            new Predicate() {
                public boolean evaluate(final Object object) {
                    return ((Integer) object) > 2;
                }
            }
    );
```

In case if you would like to select item(s) use

```
CollectionUtils.select(Collection inputCollection, Predicate predicate)
```

Use true java way - Navigable set and maps

```
NavigableSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, boolean fromInclusive,
                       E toElement,   boolean toInclusive);
```

Answer (score 3):

just use guava library as the simplest solution:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html
or
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `ArrayList`. Example:

```
/** Returns all strings starting with the letter a.*/
public static List<String> getStartsWithA(String[] strs) {
  List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String s: strs) {
    if (s.startsWith("a") || s.startsWith("A")) {
      ret.add(s);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

`ArrayList`'s internal array will dynamically grow as more space is needed.